# maven-enforcer-plugin - where to configure in Maven

Tags: xml, maven, settings, release, maven-release-plugin

Where do I need to configure this plugin.

Does it need to go in settings.xml level or in each project or sub-project's pom.xml file level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on which project/module you would like to apply your enforcer rule.

```
E.g. 
Parent -- pom.xml
|
|----module 1-------> pom.xml
|
|----module 2-------> pom.xml
```

If you would like to apply your rule on child module two - add it pom.xml of module 2.

If you would like to make your plugin visible to all your modules, add it in pom.xml of parent project.

If you would to make your plugin visible to the projects all across your environment/org/company, create a bom (bill of materials) for your environment/org/company. Add your plugin to bom. Publish bom to the repository and configure it in your project as parent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting the code in settings.xml at ~/.m2, but it's not giving an error even if there are -SNAPSHOT entries in pom files (at various levels in the project). I'm wondering if I have to put the code in every pom.

Comment: I haven't seen plugins configured in settings.xml file. See the link - http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Adding-plugin-to-settings-xml-td512724.html.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) in the usual places like this:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireSameVersions>
                  <plugins>
                    <plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin</plugin>
                    <plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin</plugin>
                    <plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin</plugin>
                  </plugins>
                </requireSameVersions>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>${maven.version}</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>    
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Thanks. But, my question was where to put the above code. In settings.xml OR in pom.xml (root, parent, module pom)?

Comment: Other clarification, if I put the above code in settings.xml at ~/.m2 or at $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml, will it cascade the effect of maven-enforcer-plugin to any project/sub-project(module/child
)? Thanks.

Comment: If you read my answer and taken a look into my given link you should know the answer which is. Put it in the pom. settings.xml can't be cause it's no possible to have a build section in the settings nor within the profile in settings.xml